# Translating a 3D grid into 2D array indices

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I want to translate the following C routine into a CUDA kernel.

And, I want to use all the dimensions in the grid to run the kernel.

How can I calculate the indices of the row and column of the matrix?

```
void OuterProduct(float* A, float* B, float** C, int N)
{
    for(int r=0 ; r<N ; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0 ; c<N ; c++)
        {
            for(int cc=0 ; cc<N ; cc++)
            {
                (*C)[r * N + c] += A[r * N + cc] * B[cc * N + c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my understanding:

Suppose the above routine is meant to multiply two 3x3 matrices. So, the number of computations would be 3x3x3 = 27. So, we need 27 threads to complete the multiplication.

Suppose we will use one thread per block. So, we need 27 blocks.

```
dim3 threads_per_block(3, 3, 3);
dim3 blocks_per_grid(3, 3, 3);
```

```
typedef float I;  
__global__ void OuterProductKernel(I* A, I* B, I* C, int N)
{
    int dimx = N;
    int dimy = N;
    int dimz = N;

    int r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int c = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int d = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (r < N && c < N && d < N) 
    {
        int loc_c = d * dimx * dimy + c * dimx + r;
 
        for (int cc=0; cc<N; cc++) 
        {
            int loc_a = (cc * dimx * dimy) + (c * dimx) + r;
            int loc_b = (d * dimx * dimy) + (cc * dimx) + r;
                    C[loc_c] += A[loc_a]*B[loc_b];
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct? I think not.

Can you give me the correct rationale for calculating `loc_a`, `loc_b`, and `loc_c`?

Comment: Can you tell where did you get this from? . Presumably the arrays are divided in blocks that start at indices `loc_a`/`b`/`c`.

Comment: @alfC, *Can you tell where did you get this from?* --- My brain.

Comment: If the matrices/arrays are two dimensional, why do you think you need three dimensional indexing in the kernel for? Literally everything you need to know to implement this is neatly summarised on this Wikipedia page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: @talonmies, *If the matrices/arrays are two dimensional, why do you think you need three dimensional indexing in the kernel for?* --- Coz, I am doing an experiment.

Comment: @talonmies, *Literally everything you need to know to implement this is neatly summarised on this Wikipedia page: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order* --- No, it is not. It is like saying, "since you know math, now you should also know how to build a rocket".

Comment: What is the experiment? How to incorrectly multiply two matrices together? How to waste vast amounts of GPU cycles doing redundant calculations?

Comment: @talonmies, *What is the experiment?* --- The experiment is about how to map 3D blocks into 2D (or, rather 1D) array indices.

Comment: You are telling us there are 27 calculations and you need 27 threads (you don't, but let's keep the gedankenexperiment going). So then you show us a block size of 27 threads, a grid size of 27 blocks, and a kernel which performs N=3 calculations per thread. That is 2187 calculations, not 27....

Comment: @talonmies, I will not respond to your comment.

Comment: @user366312 , are you asking SO to explain the _rationale_ for something that you got from your _brain_? Can you explain it to us instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion here on many levels -- array indexing, the CUDA execution model, the mathematical operation itself.

Starting from basics: the element wise operation in matrix multiplication or dot product between two matrices A and B is basically

```
C[x,y] = dot(A[x,:], B[:,y]) for all [x,y] in [0...N-1,0...N-1]
```

where

```
dot(A[x,:], B[:,y]) = A[x,0]*B[0,y] + A[x,1]*B[1,y] + ... + A[x,N-1]*B[N-1,y]
```

(Note: you refer this as "outer product", but that is either the Kronecker product or a tensor product depending on how you wish to define it, both of which are completely different from the operation your serial reference code is performing)

If you are wanting to use a three dimensional grid, then it would follow that the third dimension would need to be the dimension along the "inside" of the dot product. Assuming we have row major ordering in both arrays, let's define a little helper function:

```
__device__ size_t rowmajoridx(size_t row, size_t col, size_t lda)
{
    return col * lda + row;
}
```

and then the kernel simply becomes:

```
template<typename T>  
__global__ void DotProductKernel(T* A, T* B, T* C, int N)
{  
    int r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int c = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int d = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (r < N && c < N && d < N) 
    {
        C[rowmajidx(r,c,N)] += A[rowmajoridx(r,d,N)] * B[rowmajoridx(d,c,N)); 
    }
}
```

With a little bit of abstraction, it is clear to see that only two of the three thread indices are ever used to index any of the arrays: r and c for C, r and d for A, d and c for B. They are, after all, only N x N in size.

Note, however, that this kernel won't actually work correctly. Because there are many threads contributing to each output entry in `C`, you have a many way memory race. And `C` would need to be zeroed before the kernel was run. To fix the memory race you would need to use [atomic memory transactions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#atomic-functions), which are many of orders of magnitude slower than standard memory writes and not supported for every type on all hardware. In that case the kernel becomes something like:

```
template<typename T>  
__global__ void DotProductKernel(T* A, T* B, T* C, int N)
{  
    int r = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int c = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int d = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (r < N && c < N && d < N) 
    {
        T ans = A[rowmajoridx(r,d,N)] * B[rowmajoridx(d,c,N));
        atomicAdd(C + rowmajidx(r,c,N), ans);
    }  
}
```

In this version, the contents of `C` also need to be zeroed before the kernel is launched to avoid undefined behaviour from using uninitialised memory.

[Note all this code written in the browser, never compiled never tested, use at own risk]

Answer (score 0):

CUDA (as C and C++) uses [Row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so the code like

```
int loc_c = d * dimx * dimy + c * dimx + r;
```

should be rewritten as

```
int loc_c = d * dimx * dimy + r * dimx + c;
```

The same with the other "locs": loc_a and loc_b.

Also:

1. Make sure that the C array is zeroed, you never do this in code
2. It would be nice to see the calling code.

But if your goal is performance in most cases you will win more from caching, memory alignment and aliasing.

See, for example: [CUDA Matrix-Matrix Multiplication](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/%7Emthomas/sp17.605/lectures/CUDA-Mat-Mat-Mult.pdf)

Comment: other two locs are correct?

Comment: These are only two dimensional arrays, there is no need for the third dimension in the indexing, it is incorrect to do so

Comment: @talonmies, If you don't post answers, please don't prevent others from doing it.

Comment: Please read my answer: "the same with other locs".

Comment: @DamirTenishev, The arrays are 2D (or, rather 1D). But, I want to exploit 3D blocks.

Comment: Well, now I finally got the idea. talonmies is mostly correct here, you won't win much from this expect for some very specific cases (like huge clusters where third dimension could work, distributing the work among adapter clusters), but in most cases, this is useless and resource wasting. I've updated my answer, you may benefit from reading the article, link for which I added to the answer.

Comment: This is still wrong. Each array is only NxN in size and can only be indexed in two dimensions. It is clear that `d * dimx * dimy + c * dimx + r` will be much larger than N * N when `dimx` and `dimy`  are both N and `r,c,d` can each be as large as (N-1)